# Adobe Audition: How to turn point-in-time modifications of effects rack off?

Tags: adobe-audition

I am new to AA and I have problems with effect settings: whenever I apply settings they only get applied point-in-time, not globally like in Ableton Live. Examples: (1) I modify settings of a VST plugin (it immediately snaps-back when I release the mouse button), (2) I turn the effects rack on and off again, it is applied point-in-time.

This happens when I do modifications while I play the recording to get a preview of what the effect does. However, I do not want to apply this effect point-in-time, but globally for the whole track. How do I turn this point-in-time feature off?

Comment: idk Audition, but it sounds like it's recording the point in time info to an automation track. Cubendo can do the same thing; to fix you can either disable that automation lane entirely, or drag the 'PIT' data to the head of your cue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I enabled it accidentally

Answer (score 2):

I had to disable the automation. I accidentally enabled it ("Touch"), but have to set it to "Off":

[image]